# How to use key to filter with range and why it's slower than between directly?

Tags: r, data.table

Using the data from Introduction to data.table and making some replications

```
library(data.table)
input <- if (file.exists("flights14.csv")) {
   "flights14.csv"
} else {
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rdatatable/data.table/master/vignettes/flights14.csv"
}
flights <- fread(input)
flights

dt <- rbindlist(replicate(n = 100, expr = flights, simplify = FALSE))
setkeyv(dt,'month')
```

Suppose that I want to filter the months 5, 6, 7 and 8. Then I can do it using the key

```
dt[.(c(5,6,7,8))]
```

or with `between`

```
dt[between(month,5,8)]

> all.equal(dt[between(month, 5, 8)], dt[.(c(5,6,7,8))])
[1] TRUE
```

I measure the `system.time`using both ways and I got

```
> system.time(dt[.(c(5,6,7,8))])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.91    0.20    0.78 
> system.time(dt[between(month, 5, 8), verbose = TRUE])
between parallel processing of integer took    0.036s
   user  system elapsed 
   0.70    0.17    0.51
```

I have two questions

i) Is there a way to filter ranged values directly using the key variables or I need to use `between` passing the variable name?

ii) Why is the second approach using `between`faster than the first using the key variable?

**EDIT:** About the times, when I pass multiple values as `key` like in the first approach, internally is it looking for one value at time or all the values simultaneously? I ask it because testing the first approach with a single value it's about 1/4 of the time.

**EDIT2:** Using `on` to subset

```
> system.time(dt[.(c(5,6,7,8)), on = 'month'])
   user  system elapsed 
   1.11    0.19    0.92 
> all.equal(dt[.(c(5,6,7,8)),on = 'month'], dt[between(month, 5,8)][order(month)])
[1] TRUE
```

**times:**

a. using `on`

```
> microbenchmark(dt[.(c(5,6,7,8)), on = 'month'])
Unit: milliseconds
                               expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 dt[.(c(5, 6, 7, 8)), on = "month"] 902.6143 928.9208 1107.647 1064.389 1218.027 1771.322   100
```

b. using `between`

```
> microbenchmark(dt[between(month, 5,8)])
Unit: milliseconds
                     expr      min      lq     mean   median       uq max neval
 dt[between(month, 5, 8)] 482.6147 499.077 601.2936 612.7822 670.9884 994   100
```

c. using month as key

```
> microbenchmark(dt[.(c(5,6,7,8))])
Unit: milliseconds
                 expr      min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 dt[.(c(5, 6, 7, 8))] 744.0166 756.106 858.1838 773.7258 936.9275 1241.372   100
```

Answer (score 1):

To use key variable only, but use a range, just use `seq`

```r
dt[.(seq(5,8))]
```

```r
Unit: milliseconds
                        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
       range_with_seq_on_key 486.1632 535.6169 643.5530 628.3633 715.7411 1113.851   100
 range_with_between_on_month 387.0860 434.9599 557.6861 532.4342 630.5033 1039.224   100
```

Comment: it's the same than I did with `c()` and the speed is a little slower here, but not significantly `Unit: milliseconds
             expr      min       lq    mean   median       uq     max neval
 dt[.(seq(5, 8))] 747.5975 760.5256 874.094 864.2525 946.7829 1230.01   100`

Comment: @R.Cowboy, yes it does look like your benchmark using `c(5,6,7,8)` is a little faster.  I think you were originally asking for a way to get filter using a range, hence the `seq(5,8)` approach